# Broadcasting of Messages in Veins example

Tags: omnet++

I noticed that in the **Veins** demo scenario a node broadcasts the data message it creates to each and every other node in the simulation.

I tried to modify that a bit. I modified the `sendMessage()` function in `TraCIDemo11p.cc` file by initializing the address of the recipient in the `WSM`using the `setRecipientAddress()` function. But while running the simulation in `Veins 3.0`, I find that this message is still being broadcast to all the nodes apart from the target node.

- How do I implement this p2p connection?
- How do I generalize by adding an **RSU** to the scenario to implement a **heterogeneous communication framework**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its basis the **802.11p** standard, which is the main communication standard for Vehicular Communication (and also the one used in Veins), does broadcast.

So basically, whatever you send via a **802.11p** network interface, it will always be broadcasted, however you can make-up some type of p2p by doing "source-destination checking" from the frames.

You can extend the `WaveShortMessage` to contain **Source** and **Destination** fields specific for your application, and then perform checks if the destination is receiving from the intended sender.

---

Lets say we have two nodes `nodeSender` and `nodeReceiver` who want to communicate.

`nodeSender` would need to include its own identifier (name, ID etc) in the message:

```
msgToSend->setSourceAddress("nodeSender")
```

`nodeReceiver` would need to check if the message it "hears" is from the intended sender. Because in reality it will be hearing from multiple senders due to the broadcast nature of 80211p

```
if(receivedMsg->getSourceAddress() == 'nodeSender')
{
    /* this is the message which I need */
else
{
    /* do nothing with the message from other senders */
}
```

---

You can use vehicles SUMO id as their unique identifier for the addresses. You can obtain that by querying the `TraCIMobility` module:

```
cModule *tmpMobility = getParentModule()->getSubmodule("veinsmobility");
mobility = dynamic_cast<Veins::TraCIMobility*>(tmpMobility);
ASSERT(mobility);
mySumoID = mobility->getExternalId();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But these fields already exist in the WSM format by the name `senderAddress` and `recipientAddress`. But now that you said, I think that these broadcasted messages are really received by all the nodes and, during this reception, as it is found out that this is a data message, every node calls it's `onData()` method and performs some action regardless of whether it is meant for it or not. That's why even though the received WSM isn't meant for a node, it is accessing and unpacking the message and using it, which doesn't make sense because actual systems don't do that.

Comment: But anyways, I got the logic you have mentioned. Really appreciate your reply, helped me solve the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: addendum: regarding your first comment. usually when you create an application of your own it is highly recommended to use a message specific for your application. I have roughly explained that here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30735897/4786271